# Payer email as param in PayPal response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I have a rails app in which a user can purchase a product using PayPal's express checkout without creating an account on our site.

After the user confirms the order back on our site, I would like to send a receipt to the user. I currently have a field requesting the user to enter their email address for this purpose. However, I would instead like to be able to automatically send the receipt without the user entering their email address.

Is there a way to request the users email in the response params from PayPal?

Currently the only params I'm receiving back are `PayerID` and `token`.

I am using the [paypal-sdk-rest gem](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-ruby).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by emailing PayPal themselves.

The api reference is here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#look-up-a-payment-resource

The response returns a payer object: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#payer-object

And an example can be found here: https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-ruby/blob/master/samples/payment/find.rb

Essentially it's

```
require 'paypal-sdk-rest'
include PayPal::SDK::REST

payment = Payment.find(payment_id) # This does a call to paypal.
payer_email = payment.payer.payer_info.email
```

Answer (score 0):

The email for the buyer would come back in the GetExpressCheckoutDetails response.

Comment: I'm not seeing that response. I can only find GetExpressCheckoutDetails in the merchant-sdk-ruby gem. It doesn't seem I should be installing that gem since I'm already using the paypal-sdk-rest gem.

Comment: Ah, well first, I would recommend sticking with the Classic API for awhile.  It's much more mature than the REST API, and you will undoubtedly find yourself wishing you had features that Classic has but REST doesn't.  In fact, this may very well be one of those cases.  I really haven't played with REST too much because of the limitations, but it seems like there was a stage where it would get data back from PayPal.  That would be the equivalent of the Classic GetExpressCheckoutDetails, but I can't promise that it contains all of the same details.